# AppBarLayout doesn't work correctly with the view pager

Tags: android, android-layout, android-design-library

I am newbie to `AppBarLayout` and I got some problems. Firstly, I have a design. I got `CoordinatorLayout`, which contains `AppBarLayout`( with the `CollapsingToolbarLayout` insides with Image View ) and Below is `ViewPager` (`id = newOrder_viewPager` ). My aim is, I want to scroll vertically the view Pager, then `ImageView` of `AppBarLayout` want to be collapsing. Please help me. Here my xml code..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/background_light"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    >

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/main.appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        >

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/main.collapsing"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/main.backdrop"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:src="@drawable/office_back"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>


    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/newOrder_viewPager"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [Cheesesquare Sample project on github](https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare).
It has examples on how to use `AppBarLayout` with `ViewPager`.

Specifically, look at the `CheeseDetailActivity` (and its layout).